# error C2259: '<someclass>' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

Am getting this compiler error while trying to compile an VS 6 VC++ code. The `<someclass>` is not an abstract class. And when clicked on the error the pointer points to list system file at the first line of the function

```
void resize(size_type _Newsize, _Ty _Val)       
{     
     if (_Mysize < _Newsize)  
         _Insert_n(end(), _Newsize - _Mysize, _Val);  
     else  
     while (_Newsize < _Mysize)  
        pop_back();  
}
```

Strange. Any solutions.  Class ,

```
class SomeClass: public parentObject
{

  public:
    SomeClass() {}
    SomeClass(const someotherclass& p, double uu, double vv)
        { z= p; u = uu; v = vv; }
protected:
    double      u, v;       
     someotherclass z;  
};
```

Comment: Question 1: Visual Studio 6? Really? Question 2: Could you please post the code of your class - preferrably a minimized version that reproduces the bahavior?

Comment: What is `someclass`?  What line does the error message correspond to?

Comment: You said it's not an abstract class, but clearly the compiler thinks so.  I'm betting the compiler is right.

Comment: @Armen: Am compiling the code written in VS6 now in VS2008. I could see the class as Non-Abstract when I place the cursor over it. But it is derived from an abstract class. Will that do any harm?

Comment: @Oli: The error corresponds to the first line of the code I have posted in my question.

Comment: Is _Ty in function definition a <someclass> or base asbtract class?

Comment: @Venkatesh: A class is non-abstract when all pure virtual methods are implemented, not when your IDE says so. Have you looked below that error message, due to what methods it's considered non-abstract?

Comment: `resize` is probably `vector::resize`. That means a vector is being used. Kindly show which type is passed to `vector`? The same type is abstract

Comment: @Vankatesh: Just because the compiler points to a specific line does not mean that this is the _origin_ of the error. It is simply where the error was first _detected_; the origin can be elsewhere. Just like how making a pointer NULL is the origin of a crash, but the place where someone uses that pointer is what the debugger shows. We need to see your class definition.

Comment: @Nicol: Thats my problem. Am not sure where it arises.

Comment: If I did not implement a virtual function from `parentobject` in the `someclass` will it be still virtual?

Comment: @Venkatesh: if `parentObject` is abstract, and `SomeClass` doesn't provide non-pure overrides of *all* of its pure virtual functions, then `SomeClass` is also abstract, and can't be instantiated.

Comment: Cool. I believed the stupid IDE. And please bear with me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of a class if it has any pure-virtual members. Whether those pure-virtual members were declared in that class or in a *base class*. A class cannot be created unless all of its members exist. A class that has pure-virtual members (whether declared in the class or in a base class) is called an abstract class.

So if you inherit from a base class that has pure-virtual members, you *must* implement these in the derived class if you want to create instances of that class (like putting them in a `std::vector`).

You can put pointers to an abstract class in a `std::vector`. But only pointers, not the object themselves. So you would need to allocate your objects with `new`, but since the class is abstract you cannot create them at all. So you will need to derive a new class that implements the pure-virtual methods. And then you will be able to create that class and put it in your `std::vector<someclass*>`.

Comment: I hope your answer helps. Let me check.